# How to test the bolierplate code written in __init__.py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a package that is developed in python with the following project structure:

```
sample_package

    -sample
            - sample_module.py
            - __init__.py
    -tests
            -test_sample.py
```

I have written some boilerplate code in the init.py file. To test the methods defined in the `sample_module`, I have imported the `sample_module` in `test_sample.py`.

Now, every time I run a single test indivisually, it is obvious that because of importing the `sample_module`, the boilerplate code written in init.py file will get executed.

I want to avoid such scenario (execution of init.py for every test) and have control over its execution. How do we do that?

MRE for test_sample.py:

```
from sample.sample_module import X, Y, Z

def test_X():
    ....

def test_Y():
    ....

def test_Z():
    ....
```

MRE for init.py:

```
from sample.sample_module import T

def load_setting():
    ....
    T()
    ....

if __name__ == "sample_module":
    load_settings()
```

I do not want that the function `load_setting()` should get executed every time for each test.

Comment: `from sample import function_under_test`?

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer, I imported the functions in the same way as you wrote. But still the same issue.

Comment: Every test function shouldn't be importing the module or those functions. You should only need one import in `test_sample.py`. Can you please show a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, added MRE for test_sample.py

Comment: Can you please show the content of the init file that should/shouldn't be tested / run as well? As well as how you're noticing that it is being ran?

Comment: If you want to test the init file, you need to import from just `sample`, not `sample_module`

Comment: Don't think the "only once" part is possible.

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding the problem. How are you seeing that anything **is** being loaded more than once?